# How to run PIT tests with Maven in IDEA?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I added PIT to my pom.xml as described here: http://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/

According to that page, it has added mutationCoverage goals to Maven. However, I don't see those goals in my "Maven Projects" window in IDEA under my project name / Lifecycle. I also haven't found any way to add goals. I scoured through the pages about Maven on Jetbrains but didn't find anything.

There seems to be a PIT plugin for IDEA, but if I have to install a plugin for each dependency, then I don't understand what the role of Maven is?

Can I somehow run PIT tests with Maven in IDEA?

Comment: I would run pitest only from command line cause it can take very long..depending on the mutations you are using....BTW: Maven is the build tool...IntelliJ is your IDE...they have nothing to do with each other...

Answer (score 2):

View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects

Project name -> Lifecycle -> Right click on `test`, select `create...`

Now on top of "Maven Projects" there should be a drop down box with "Project name [test]". Select `edit configurations` from the dropdown choices.

In the window that opens, add the following to 'command line': `clean install test org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`